# Par quoi remplacer « moins pire » ?

Tags: oral, superlatifs, comparatifs

Je me retrouve souvent à vouloir dire « moins pire » dans une phrase, bien que je sache que c'est incorrect. Existe-t-il une reformulation de la phrase qui me permettrait de véhiculer le sens de *par défaut* mais pas tellement mieux que ça ?

En fait, le problème se pose surtout à l'oral. Comment devrais-je commencer mes phrases pour éviter de devoir utiliser « moins pire » ?

Si rien n'est mentionné antérieurement, *pire* est indéfini et donc englobe tout (impossible de le remplacer ?).

<sub>PS : je souhaite une réponse pour le français *standard* (pas québécois par exemple).</sub>

Comment: Une remarque : le post-scriptum m'a paru complètement déplacé avant que je ne me rende compte que « moins pire » est une tournure couramment acceptée au Québec. Il serait sûrement préférable de l'indiquer dans ta question.

Comment: @stéph ton commentaire fera l'affaire. Jte remercie pour la remarque.

Comment: Tu peux l'utiliser dans une phrase qu'on te corrigerais? Parce que comme ça, je dirais «meilleur», mais à mon avis, ce n'est pas ce que tu recherches.

Comment: Pensez positif: *mieux* ou *meilleur* peut être moins grave que *moins pire* ;-)

Comment: Au Québec on dirait aussi, "pas si pire".

Answer (score 14):

Je dirais simplement « moins mauvais » ou « le moins mauvais » dans le cas d'un superlatif
 (voir le [tableau des comparatifs et des superlatifs](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/Annexe%3aGrammaire_fran%C3%A7aise%3aComparatif_et_superlatif) sur le Wikitionnaire).
Mais, n'étant pas québécois, il y a peut-être une nuance que je ne perçois pas.

Comment: @Knu avec la phrase « Jean est le moins mauvais » on comprend que l'autre est pire, d'ailleurs « pire » est le comparatif de supériorité de l'adjectif « mauvais » [CNRTL](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/pire)

Comment: je pense qu'en français c'est la solution aussi

Comment: Au début, j'ai pensé que le sens québécois pouvait utiliser « *X* est moins pire qu'*Y* » et « *X* est le moins pire » pour dire quelque chose similaire à « *X* est moins plus petit que *Y* » et « *X* est le moins plus petit » (sans vraiment comprendre dans quel cas cela pouvait s'appliquer). Mais en fait, vu l'exemple que tu donnes, à présent je pense vraiment que la signification recherchée est exactement celle de « moins mauvais ».

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez *pire* implique que Jean fait partie des pires. Alors que lorsque l'on utilise *mauvais* on pourrait comparer 2 très bons escrimeurs par exemple et dire que « Jean est le moins mauvais » (sous entendu qu'il est le meilleur) se maintenant ainsi dans un spectre positif. Avec *moins pire* on est sûr de véhiculer le sens de *faute de mieux* (parmi les pires). J'espère que ça clarifie mon propos.

Comment: Ok, je crois que c'est un peu plus clair. En plus de la comparaison, tu souhaites préciser que tous se situent très bas dans l'échelle. En fait, « moins mauvais » remplit déjà un peu ce rôle. Si tu parles de très bons escrimeurs en disant « Jean est le moins mauvais », ils ne vont pas du tout apprécier ! La comparaison qui vient naturellement c'est « meilleur », et la différence qu'il y a avec « moins mauvais » c'est justement la position dans l'échelle. Si tu veux insister un peu plus lourdement sur leur niveau déplorable, c'est vrai que le français n'offre pas plus que cette seule nuance.

Answer (score 13):

Si tu veux garder le *pire*, peut-être peux-tu simplement remplacer le *moins*, et dire que la solution choisie n'est *pas la pire* ?

> Chéri, tu veux des haricots, du chou, ou des navets ?
>   Va pour les haricots, c'est pas le pire.

Mais j'avoue que ça cloche encore un peu. Note que tu peux aussi utiliser *ça aurait pu être pire* :

> Chéri, tu veux du chou ou des haricots ?
>   Ça aurait pu être pire, tu aurais pu proposer des navets.

De plus, tu sembles indiquer que tu cherches comment le remplacer en début de phrase, j'imagine que c'est pour introduire une alternative, et là je rejoins un peu Stéphane, *moins grave* me paraît approprié.

Ou alors, dans certains cas, je pense que tu peux utiliser le proverbe correspondant :

> De deux maux, il faut choisir le moindre.

Ou l'expression dérivée *un moindre mal* :

> A choisir, Jean est le moindre mal.

Mais à vrai dire, je crois qu'une phrase comme « A choisir, jean est le moins pire » sera quand même parfaitement comprise partout, donc en suivant une approche descriptiviste, je répondrais simplement de ne pas te tracasser et de continuer à l'utiliser tel quel. Tu n'es d'ailleurs [pas le seul](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=moins+pire&year_start=1800&year_end=2010&corpus=7&smoothing=3), et ça m'étonnerait que ça se limite au Québec.

Comment: "tu sembles indiquer que tu l'utilises en début de phrase" non du tout je cherche juste une tournure de phrase qui m’empêcherait de pouvoir l'utiliser (c'est l'inverse donc).

Comment: Je voulais dire que comme tu demandais « Comment devrais-je _commencer_ mes phrases », je pensais que tu utilisais _moins pire_ en début de phrase, et que tu cherchais à le remplacer là. J'ai accordé trop d'importance à ça, désolé. Sinon, n'hésite pas à rajouter les exemples dans la question même ; dans le cas de Jean je pense que le proverbe est ce qui est encore le plus simple. Cela dit, _Jean est le moins pire_ sera compris partout, je rajoute un morceau de réponse en ce sens.

Comment: Joubarc, pour le ngram, en regardant les premiers liens (parmi 2000 entrées, ce qui est très faible en fait), on constate qu'il s'agit souvent de bouquins de français qui référencent la faute, ou de « moins pire » qui sont entre guillemets.

Comment: @Stéphane je savais bien que je ne devais pas regarder de trop près :-)

Comment: @Joubarc j'ai un exemple réel qui supporte ton approche. Mélenchon a utilisé *moins pire* dans un discours puis, le suivant, est passé à *moindre mal*; on a du le reprendre.

Answer (score 8):

D'après la remarque générale n<sup>o</sup> 1 du [CNRTL](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/pire) :

> Pire n'étant pas toujours senti (notamment au Québec) comme un comparatif ou un superlatif, *moins pire*, *plus pire*, *aussi pire* ou *très pire* peuvent apparaître dans la langue populaire ou parlée.

« Pire » est un comparatif, on dirait « Jeannot est pire que Jean » ou « Jean est le moins mauvais ».

Answer (score 3):

Bien que le sens soit légèrement différent, j'aime bien [*pis-aller*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/pis-aller), qui sonne très français standard.

Answer (score 2):

Pire est moral :

> Jean est le pire de la classe (il embête tout le monde).
>
> Jean est le plus mauvais joueur de tennis.

« Moins pire » ne se dit pas. On devra reformuler et dire « il y a encore pire que lui », car il faut maintenir la connotation morale.

Answer (score 2):

Je me suis fait reprendre par une gamine qui m'a dit « On dit ***préférable*** et pas *moins pire* ! »

Answer (score 1):

Peut-être juste « c'est pas pire ».

Comment: je me demande maintenant si cette réponse n'est pas encore moins meilleure que "moins pire"

Comment: En tout cas, « moins meilleure » est tout aussi mauvais que « moins pire » ;-) Quant à « c'est pas pire » ça peut être correct, mais il faut le comprendre comme l'opposé de « c'est pas meilleur/mieux ».

Answer (score 0):

On ne dit pas *moins pire*. Ceci est une expression utilisée mais incorrecte.

On dit *mieux* ou *meilleur* avec éventuellement la solution opposée.

Par exemple, on ne dit pas :

> C'est moins pire de faire ceci.

Mais on dit :

> C'est mieux de faire cela.

Comment: Ce n'est vraiment pas la question.

Comment: La question est "par quoi remplacer "moins pire" ?". Ma réponse est "moins pire est incorrecte, on utilise "meilleur" ou "mieux".".

Comment: La question est « Je me retrouve souvent à vouloir dire « moins pire » dans une phrase, bien que je sache que c'est incorrect. Existe-t-il une reformulation de la phrase qui me permettrait de véhiculer le sens de par défaut mais pas tellement mieux que ça ? » tout le monde ici sait déjà que c'est incorrect, il s'agit de savoir quoi faire quand *mieux* n'est pas adapté.

Comment: Si tu ne veux ni de "pire" ni de "meilleur" alors la reformulation de la phrase ne sera pas générique et dépendra du contexte. Tu peux fournir un exemple de phrase à reformuler ? La notion de "on prends ça par défaut parce que c'est pas le meilleur mais tant pis" est impossible selon moi à transformer en "expression générique".

Answer (score 0):

J’ai vu aussi « c’est pire QUE pire » pour dire « c’est pire QUE tout » donc peut-être en n'ajoutant que *QUE*, on pourrait dire « **moins (ou plus ?) que pire** » (un peu comme l’idée de « plus-que-parfait »). 
Autrement, j’aime bien la réponse de @Joubarc (le moindre mal) et je crois que ça marcherait aussi au pluriel : « le moindre des maux/mauvais/pires » .

Answer (score -1):

Pour moi, le pire de ce probleme se situe dans le mot "pire", "le moins" n'etant pas pire que "pire". Je suggererais donc un petit synonyme moins pire que "pire" tel que "penalisant" par exemple. Mais n'hesites pas a "pire-ouetter" ta phrase en passant du moins pire au plus interessant.
La vie est belle, ne l'em-pir-ons pas ! ;) 
(en quoerti)