# Pourquoi si peu d'amour pour « pis » ?

Tags: grammaire, histoire, comparatifs, adverbes

Parcourant le tableau qui résume les [exceptions](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/Annexe%3aGrammaire_fran%C3%A7aise%3aComparatif_et_superlatif#Exceptions) parmi les comparatifs, je viens de (re)découvrir que *pis* était à l'adverbe *mal* ce que *pire* est à l'adjectif *mauvais*.

Les comparatifs voisins (*mieux*, *meilleur* ou *pire*) sont très fréquents (voire [trop](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/1255/par-quoi-remplacer-moins-pire)), on eût donc pu croire que naturellement il en fût de même pour *pis*… mais non ! De nos jours presque personne ne l'utilise, et [ngrams](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=bien%2Cmieux%2Cmal%2Cpis&year_start=1650&year_end=2000&corpus=7&smoothing=7) nous laisse penser que ça a longtemps été comme ça :

[image]

Il y a pourtant quelques expressions courantes telles que *tant pis*, ou de plus rares *pis-aller*¹, qui l'utilisent.
Et même s'il me semble parfois possible de l'employer sous quelques formes, comme dans :

> Il ne saurait rien arriver de pis.

voici d'autres phrases dans lesquelles il ne me viendrait jamais à l'idée de l'employer (alors qu'à sa place, *mieux* ne me poserait aucun problème) :

> C'est pas *pis* !
>   Il s'exprime *pis* que moi !

Doit-on considérer que ces phrases sont correctes ? Fut-il un temps où ce genre d'utilisation était courant ?

*Question bonus* : Des mots qu'offrent les bouquins de grammaire, il semble qu'aucun ne soit *pis* aimé que celui-ci. Y aurait-il par hasard une explication à cela ?

—
<sup>1. @Evpok [citait](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/1255/par-quoi-remplacer-moins-pire/1268#1268) celui-ci récement.</sup>

Comment: Je pense qu'il faudrait plutôt comparer l'usage de pis et de pire, qui sont deux formes du même signifié. Quand on compare ces deux, on note un décrochage en faveur de pire vers 1900.

Comment: @subtenante: bien vu, j'avais raté cette comparaison. Par contre, je remarque que dans une grande partie des résultats récents retournés par ngrams, *pis* est utilisé comme une alternative familière à *puis* (et pas du tout comme un comparatif).

Comment: AMHA sa prononciation se rapproche trop de celle de *pire*. La seule expression encore usitée de nos jours qui me vient serait *de mal en pis*.

Comment: On lui en a fait voir pis que pendre.

Comment: @Knu : c'est pis que pendre d'oublier cette expression (une antanclase pour faire plaisir à Joubarc). (Le temps d'écrire ma réponse je n'avais pas vu que mouviciel l'avait déjà citée... je devrais supprimer mon commentaire, mais la tentation d'antanaclase est la plus forte !)

Comment: Très intéressant. Est-ce que «Tant pis» veut dire «Tellement mal»?

Comment: L'amour pour « pis » est un amour vache!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Wilmet

> Il s'exprime pis que moi !

Cette utilisation ne me choque en rien. *Pis* est un adverbe, et il est utilisé dans ce cas exactement de la même manière que le seraient *mieux*, *plus* ou *moins*, adverbes de la même famille.

Je citerais la [Grammaire Critique du Français](http://superieur.deboeck.com/titres/29080_2_0/grammaire-critique-du-francais.html) (3<sup>e</sup> édition), section 685 concernant les sous-phrases adverbiales, par exemple *Il est plus grand que je ne pensais*. Wilmet nous cite comme articulation avant le *que* :

> Adverbes concernés : *ailleurs*, *ainsi*, *aussi*, *autant*, *autrement*, *davantage* (l'archaïsme *davantage que* jugé «vulgaire», allez savoir pourquoi), *mieux*, *moins*, **pis**, *plus*, *plutôt*, *si*, *tant*, *tellement*. Plus l'adjectif *tel*, les deux adjectifs comparatifs «synthétiques» *meilleur*, **pire**, les deux adjectifs de sens «extrinsèque» *autre* et *même*. [...]

(La graisse est mienne, pour faire ressortir *pis* et *pire*.)

<s>Selon Wilmet, donc, on a également comme usage possible : *Il s'exprime **pire** que moi !*, par utilisation d'un adjectif en lieu et place d'un adverbe. Le sens me paraît identique, et aucun des deux ne me choque.</s>

Je faisais dire à Wilmet ce qu'il ne dit pas : *pire* et *meilleur* peuvent en effet introduire des sous-phrases adverbiales, mais pas avec n'importe quel verbe. Les verbes d'état, par exemple, mais pas des verbes comme *aller*, *parler*, ou *s'exprimer*. Et si aux petites heures nocturnes, l'utilisation de *pire* ne me gênait pas, en plein soleil il semble bien qu'elle pose problème.

> C'est pas pis !

Là encore, on substituerait facilement *mieux* <s>ou *meilleur*</s>, je ne vois donc pas d'obstacle à utiliser *pis* là où on a pris l'habitude d'utiliser *pire*. La langue étant ce qu'on en fait, et *pis* restant compréhensible, je pense que je vais me mettre à l'utiliser un peu plus souvent là où l'adverbe est attendu de préférence.

#### Grevisse

Concernant ce que disent Grevisse *et al.*, avec qui Wilmet n'est manifestement pas très d'accord, on peut lire [là](http://books.google.com/books?id=3I9juumoDBcC&pg=PA169&hl=en&ei=XGF-TqalGIij-gaU3u2RDQ&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=4&ved=0CEMQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q&f=false) que *pis* est en fait généralement un adjectif (mais peut aussi être un nom ! de même que *pire* peut l'être dans *c'est pas le pire*, on pourrait dire *c'est pas le pis*); néanmoins, Grevisse accorde la concurrence faite par *pire*, tout en citant l'exemple de Diderot *Ce qu'il y a de pis*, qui me semble très proche de *C'est pas pis*.

#### Les lapins

Comme réflection nocturne, je dirais que *pis* souffre aussi d'une homonymie avec le *pis* de, par exemple, la vache. Le *pis* était néanmoins à une époque le mot désigné pour ce qui est désormais le *sein* (la mamelle de la femme).

Le *pire* remplace-t-il le *pis* comme les *lapins* remplacèrent les *connils* ?

---

*Réponse bonus* : *oncques* n'en ai vu parler chez quelque grammairien plus extensivement qu'en une ligne lapidaire.

Comment: _C'est pas pis_ fait quand même penser qu'on parle de grand-père.

Comment: @Joubarc : certes. Quand le «pas pis» sent pire, c'est par un décret pis que pendre que l'empire de pis se décrépit. Tant pis.

Comment: Merci pour la réponse. Par contre, « il s'exprime *pire/meilleur* que moi » ça me semble vraiment « *mauvais* » formé. Les seuls adverbes (ou groupes adverbiaux) que j'emploierais dans la vraie vie seraient *mieux* ou *plus mal* (qui semble avoir remplacé *pis* dans la majorité des cas).

Comment: Hmm... en effet.

Comment: Sans commentaire des Belges et Manneken Pis ?

Answer (score 2):

Une explication un peu moins académique pourrait être:

[image]