# Peut-on dire « plus pire » ou « moins pire » ?

Tags: comparatifs

J'ai plusieurs fois entendu dire « *x* est moins pire que *y* », j'ai toujours jugé que c'était une faute de français, et je viens tout juste de lire la phrase:

> Les nouveaux Brazzas ne sont pas moins pire que les anciens [...]

Je n'ai pas de mal à associer un sens à « *x* est pire que *y*, mais moins que ne l'est *z* » bien que je sois convaincu que c'est une faute de français, mais je trouve que ça sonne faux; « *x* est pire que *y*, mais tu as raison, *z* est moins pire » sonne encore plus faux, et me fait mal aux oreilles.

Peut-on dire d'une chose qu'elle est plus (ou moins) pire qu'une autre ?

Comment: Lié: http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/1255/par-quoi-remplacer-moins-pire. C'est tordu, mais peut-être que c'est une comparaison de comparaisons :-) cf [ma remarque](http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/1255/par-quoi-remplacer-moins-pire?rq=1#comment2459_1256).

Comment: Je suis d'accord avec Stéphane.

Answer (score 2):

Dans la langue Française, on peut (je l'espère) tout comparer, même la notion de "pire". Faire sans deviendrait gênant, par exemple dans des situations comme celle-ci :

- A n'est pas bon.
- B est pire que A.
- C est pire que A.

Comment comparer B et C par rapport à A sans parler de "plus pire" ou "moins pire" ?

Comment: *C est encore pire* ?

Comment: B est encore moins bon que C ? Je pense que pire ne peut s'accompagner sans que ce soit bizarre à l'oreille.

Answer (score 2):

Je pense que l'on ne dit jamais (plus ou moins) pire, mais soit "Plus mauvais" ou "Pire".